# Minimizing problem (1-dimensional phase transition)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence, euler-lagrange-equation

I need some help in this calculus of variation exercise:

Let $X$ to be the set of functions $\chi\in H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\chi(0)=1/2$ and such that the following limits do exists:
\begin{equation*}
\chi(-\infty)=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\chi(x)=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\chi(\infty)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\chi(x)=1
\end{equation*}
Consider the functional $F:X\to[0,\infty]$
\begin{equation*}
F(\chi)=\int_\mathbb{R}(\chi'(x)^2+\chi(x)^2(1-\chi(x)^2)dx
\end{equation*}

Compute the following:

1) Consider a minimizing sequence $\chi_n$, prove that it can be chosen monotone and such that $0\leq\chi_n\leq 1$ and extract a subsequence that is weekly converging in $H^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$.

2) Study lower semicontinuity.

3) Deduce the Euler Lagrange equation in the weak form for the minimizer.

4) Does the candidate minimizer satisfy the condition at $\pm\infty$?

I know that this problem could be solved using $\Gamma$-convergence and the properties of Modica-Mortola (Ginzburg-Landau) functional but I think that the goal is to avoid that theory and only use the properties that ensure the existence of minimizers in Sobolev spaces.

**UPDATE**

Proof:

1) I've started choosing a minimizing sequence $\chi_n$ and observing that since the functional $F(\chi)\geq 0$ that sequence admits limit:
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F(\chi_n)=M 
\end{equation*}
then proved that it is not restricting to assume that $0\leq\chi_n\leq 1$ in this way:

If we have a sequence $\chi_k$ which is $>1$ in some set of non negative measure we can consider the new sequence defined by:
\begin{equation*}
 \bar\chi_k=
 \begin{cases}
  0  \ \ \text{if} \ \chi_k(x)< 0\\
  \chi_k(x) \ \ \text{if} \ 0\leq\chi_k(x)\leq 1\\
  1 \ \ \text{if} \ \chi_k(x)> 1
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
We now notice that for this new sequence the functional is identically zero when $\chi_k\in\{0,1\}$ and then we have that $F(\chi_k)\geq F(\bar{\chi}_k)$. Passing now to the limit on both sides we obtain that since $\chi_k$ is minimizing:
\begin{equation*}
  \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F(\chi_k)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F(\bar\chi_k)
\end{equation*}
so in conclusion also $\bar\chi_k$ is minimizing.

I have also proved in a similar way that it is not restrictive to assume that the sequence is monotone.

Now I have to prove that exists a minimizing sequence that is bounded in order to extract a subsequence which converges weekly to some $u$.

Can you help me with this part of the proof also giving me some hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3656675/11127

Comment: I’ve actually seen it and it is probably the same but no one has answered it yet.

Comment: Actually it doesn't because I'm looking for a strategy to prove compactenss and to study lower semicontinuity in order to apply theorems of existence of minimizers in Sobolev spaces.

Comment: @Qmechanic can you give me some advices?